# Mediation Effect of a Latent Variable in Structural Equation Modelling (SEM) using R

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I have the attached model that I want to test by using the sem package in R, and the full model (model 3) runs smoothly. However, later on, when I want to test the mediation effect of the variable "attitude" I ran into some troubles. R returns the following warning message, and I don't quite understand where I did wrong. Could anyone please help me? Thank you so much!

[image]

Warning message:

```
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Could not compute QR decomposition of Hessian.
Optimization probably did not converge.
```

In order to test the mediation effect of attitude. I ran 3 models, the first and the third model all worked out, except the second model, where I delete everything related to attitude. I tried my best to layout the problem (sorry that it's a bit lengthy). The yellow question marks below are the output that I was looking for.

[image]

Here are the codes that I have for the three models.

```
###############################################################Model 1
#######SEM Fully mediated MODEL 1
###############################################################

factor.data<-data.frame (cbind(ECNew,HCNew, attNew, willingNew, FunctionNew, ageNew, incomeNew, KIndexNew, genderNew))
cov.matrix<-cov(na.omit(factor.data)) 

cfa.model1<-specifyModel()
ageNew -> Attitude, gam11
incomeNew -> Attitude, gam12
genderNew -> Attitude, gam13
KIndexNew -> Attitude, gam15
ageNew -> WTB, gam21
incomeNew -> WTB, gam22
genderNew -> WTB, gam23
KIndexNew -> WTB, gam25
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_a, ec1
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_c, ec3
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_d, ec4
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_e, ec5
HealthConcisousness->Q19_a, hc1
HealthConcisousness->Q19_b, hc2
HealthConcisousness->Q19_c, hc3
Function -> Q13_l, f3
Function -> Q13_m, f4
Function -> Q13_n, f5
Function -> Q13_o, f6
Attitude->Q15_c, a3
Attitude->Q15_d, a4
Attitude->Q15_e, a5
WTB-> Q14_d, w4
WTB-> Q14_h, w6
WTB-> Q14_i, w7
WTB-> Q14_j, w8
WTB-> Q14_k, w9
EnvironmentConcern -> Attitude, EA
HealthConcisousness -> Attitude, HA
Function -> Attitude, FA
Attitude -> WTB, AW
EnvironmentConcern <-> HealthConcisousness, ps2
EnvironmentConcern <-> Function, ps3
HealthConcisousness <-> Function, ps5
EnvironmentConcern <-> EnvironmentConcern, NA, 1
HealthConcisousness <-> HealthConcisousness,NA, 1
Function <-> Function, NA, 1 
Attitude <-> Attitude, NA, 1
WTB <-> WTB,  NA, 1

cfa1<-sem(cfa.model1, cov.matrix, nrow(factor.data), fixed.x=c("ageNew","incomeNew", "KIndexNew", "genderNew"))
summary(cfa1, fit.indices = c("GFI", "AGFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "NNFI", "CFI", "RNI", "IFI", "SRMR", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "CAIC"))

###############################################################Model 2
#######SEM IV affects DV MODEL 
###############################################################
factor.data2<-data.frame (cbind(ECNew,HCNew, willingNew, FunctionNew, ageNew, incomeNew, KIndexNew, genderNew))
cov.matrix2<-cov(na.omit(factor.data2)) 

cfa.model2<-specifyModel()
ageNew -> WTB, gam21
incomeNew -> WTB, gam22
genderNew -> WTB, gam23
KIndexNew -> WTB, gam25
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_a, ec1
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_c, ec3
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_d, ec4
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_e, ec5
HealthConcisousness->Q19_a, hc1
HealthConcisousness->Q19_b, hc2
HealthConcisousness->Q19_c, hc3
Function -> Q13_l, f3
Function -> Q13_m, f4
Function -> Q13_n, f5
Function -> Q13_o, f6
WTB-> Q14_d, w4
WTB-> Q14_h, w6
WTB-> Q14_i, w7
WTB-> Q14_j, w8
WTB-> Q14_k, w9
EnvironmentConcern -> WTB, EW
HealthConcisousness->WTB, HW
Function -> WTB, FW
EnvironmentConcern <-> HealthConcisousness, ps2
EnvironmentConcern <-> Function, ps3
HealthConcisousness <-> Function, ps5
EnvironmentConcern <-> EnvironmentConcern, NA, 1
HealthConcisousness <-> HealthConcisousness,NA, 1
Function <-> Function, NA, 1 
WTB <-> WTB,  NA, 1

cfa2<-sem(cfa.model2, cov.matrix2, nrow(factor.data2), fixed.x=c("ageNew","incomeNew","KIndexNew", "genderNew"))
summary(cfa2, fit.indices = c("GFI", "AGFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "NNFI", "CFI", "RNI", "IFI", "SRMR", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "CAIC"))

###############################################################Model 3
#######SEM Fully SpecifiedMODEL 
###############################################################

factor.data3<-data.frame (cbind(ECNew,HCNew, attNew, willingNew, FunctionNew, ageNew, incomeNew, KIndexNew, genderNew))
cov.matrix3<-cov(na.omit(factor.data3)) 

cfa.model3<-specifyModel()
ageNew -> Attitude, gam11
incomeNew -> Attitude, gam12
genderNew -> Attitude, gam13
KIndexNew -> Attitude, gam15
ageNew -> WTB, gam21
incomeNew -> WTB, gam22
genderNew -> WTB, gam23
KIndexNew -> WTB, gam25
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_a, ec1
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_c, ec3
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_d, ec4
EnvironmentConcern->Q18_e, ec5
HealthConcisousness->Q19_a, hc1
HealthConcisousness->Q19_b, hc2
HealthConcisousness->Q19_c, hc3
Function -> Q13_l, f3
Function -> Q13_m, f4
Function -> Q13_n, f5
Function -> Q13_o, f6
Attitude->Q15_c, a3
Attitude->Q15_d, a4
Attitude->Q15_e, a5
WTB-> Q14_d, w4
WTB-> Q14_h, w6
WTB-> Q14_i, w7
WTB-> Q14_j, w8
WTB-> Q14_k, w9
EnvironmentConcern -> Attitude, EA
HealthConcisousness -> Attitude, HA
Function -> Attitude, FA
EnvironmentConcern -> WTB, EW
HealthConcisousness->WTB, HW
Function -> WTB, FW
Attitude -> WTB, AW
EnvironmentConcern <-> HealthConcisousness, ps2
EnvironmentConcern <-> Function, ps3
HealthConcisousness <-> Function, ps5
EnvironmentConcern <-> EnvironmentConcern, NA, 1
HealthConcisousness <-> HealthConcisousness,NA, 1
Function <-> Function, NA, 1 
Attitude <-> Attitude, NA, 1
WTB <-> WTB,  NA, 1

cfa<-sem(cfa.model3, cov.matrix3, nrow(factor.data3), fixed.x=c("ageNew","incomeNew", "KIndexNew", "genderNew"))
summary(cfa, fit.indices = c("GFI", "AGFI", "RMSEA", "NFI", "NNFI", "CFI", "RNI", "IFI", "SRMR", "AIC", "AICc", "BIC", "CAIC"))
```